# How to request a user_access_token rather than an app_access_token via OAUTH

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm attempting to pull in a user's Facebook wall/feeds via an AJAX call to my webservice.  Effectively the webservice itself just caches previous requests so that I don't have to hit Facebook every time someone wants to see a list of posts (I have them on a 30 minute cache ATM).  This works great as long as I'm pulling their "Feed" via a URL like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{0}/feed
```

where {0} is the user's ID.  However, when I just want to request the user's statuses in order to avoid all the other garbage that shows up on their wall

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{0}/statuses
```

I get an 400 request error.  I drilled down a bit deeper and here is the actual response that I recieve:

```
{
   "error": {
   "message": "(#100) Requires user session",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 100
   }
}
```

After a little bit of Googling, I believe that I have traced the issue to the fact that I am requesting an APP access token instead of a USER access token.  Currently my request string for that is in the following format:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I've been searching high and low, but I just haven't been able to find the correct format for requesting a specific user's access token.  If, for example, I wanted to pull a list of statuses for a public profile like https://www.facebook.com/DrPepper, how would I go about getting that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authorize the user (or yourself) via [oAuth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth) this will return a `code` (a random string) which gives one-time access to `/oauth/access_token` endpoint to return the `access_token`

```
/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&code={code}
```

<sup>sending the `redirect_uri` (it must match your website URL in your app dashboard) parameter will generate a 60 days `access_token`, obviously you need this</sup>

You can change response_type to `token` instead of `code` so you don't have to request `/oauth/access_token` [oAuth Dialog - Parameters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/#params)

### Another Solution

Stick with `{ID}/feed` and use app `access_token` because it never expires,

```
/{ID}/feed?fields=message,type
```

and use PHP or whatever you're using to check the `type` field

Comment: Thanks Adam!  That's precisely what I was looking for.  All in all I think I'll stick with the /feed and just look for specific types.  In terms of trade-offs, the brief code to run comparisons is a bit less of a hassle than regenerating access_tokens every 2 months or so.